# gridpanel flowing out of wrapper container

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am designing a web application in asp.net, I have encountered a serious problem the gridpanel of my form goes out of the wrapper container when the browser resizes..heres the link to my webapplication
http://everest.planetearthsolution.com/Setup/Ledgers/ChartOfAccounts.aspx

when you resize the browser or change the resolution the gridpanel flows out of the container,just try minimizing the browser and you will know what I am talking about.what am I doing wrong? heres the css

**this is the css for the master page**

```
body {
    background-color: #658A07;
}

#container {
    background-color: #F4FAE1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #B8C97F;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width: 304px;
    background-color: #F4FAE1;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: #B8C97F;

}

#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#form {
    padding-left: 314px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #DDEBB2;
    height: 15px;
    width: auto;

    border: 1px solid #B8C97F;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

#logo {
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px;
}

#breadcrumb {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #DDEBB2;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #CDDE9E;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 314px;
}


#tree {
    background: #000000;

}

.searchbox {
    background: url(Images/searchbox.png) top right no-repeat;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 296px;
    border: 1px solid #B8C97F;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.item-selector
{
    background: url('../../Resource/Icons/search-16.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 4px 4px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}
```

**and the css below is the css for gridpanel and other form contents**

```
    html, body, table, tr, td, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, input, select, p, textarea {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Tahoma', 'Arial', 'Open Sans', open-sans, 'Source Sans Pro', MyriadPro-Regular, 'Myriad Pro Regular', MyriadPro, 'Myriad Pro', 'Lucida Grande', 'Droid Sans', Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Tahoma, Geneva, Arial, 'Open Sans', open-sans, 'DejaVu Sans', 'Liberation Sans', Freesans, 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #658A07;
    cursor: pointer;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

    a, a:visited {
        color: #29690C;
    }

        h1:hover, h2:hover, h3:hover, h4:hover, h5:hover, a:hover, .menu-panel a:hover {
            color: #CC3300;
        }

.hr {
    border: 1px dotted #C0C0C0;
    border-top: 0px;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

form {
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
}

html, body, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 12px;
}

input, select {
    padding: 2px;
    color: #333399;
}

    input[readonly] {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

.error {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #CC3300;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar- {
    width: 8px;
    height: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #eee;
    border: thin solid lightgray;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #dfdfdf inset;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #999;
    border: thin solid gray;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
        background: #7d7d7d;
    }

.success {
    color: #009933;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.failure {
    color: #CC3300;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.vpad2 {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 0px;
}

.vpad4 {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px !important;
}

.vpad6 {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px !important;
}

.vpad8 {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px !important;
}

.vpad10 {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px !important;
}

.vpad12 {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 0px 12px 0px !important;
}

.vpad14 {
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 0px 14px 0px !important;
}


.vpad16 {
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 0px 16px 0px !important;
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}

.dirty {
    border: 1px solid #FF9933 !important;
}


.center {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

textarea {
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 4px;
}

.info {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #DDEBB2;
}

.pink {
    border: 1px solid #FF97FF;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #FFBBFF;
}

.red {
    border: 1px solid #FF7D7D;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #FFB7B7;
}

.yellow {
    border: 1px solid #FAD91F;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #FCEA81;
}

.purple {
    border: 1px solid #E0B3FF;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #EFD7FF;
}

.green {
    border: 1px solid #A3FF46;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #CCFF99;
}

.linkblock {
    padding: 4px;
    border-color: #E1E1E1;
    border-style: none none dotted none;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: block;
}

input.date {
    background: white url(../../Resource/Icons/calendar-16.png) no-repeat scroll;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
    padding-right: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #E0EDC0;
    color: #333333;
}

    .description:hover {
        background-color: #D2E6A1;
    }

.button {
    margin-left: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #658A07;
    border: 1px solid #60a338;
}


    .button:hover {
        /*background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #8cb82b), color-stop(1, #9dce2c) );
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( center top, #8cb82b 5%, #9dce2c 100% );*/
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8cb82b', endColorstr='#9dce2c');
        background-color: #8cb82b;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .button:active {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
/* This imageless css button was generated by CSSButtonGenerator.com */

.valignmiddle tr td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}


.linkbutton {
    color: #9900CC !important;
}

.scrud-menu, .scrud-menu:visited {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #658A07;
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #658A07;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

    .scrud-menu:hover {
        background-color: #4E6B04;
        border: 1px solid #4E6B04;
        color: White;
    }




.grid {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #9dce2c;
}

    .grid tbody tr:hover, .grid tbody tr.alt:hover {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: #E0EDBE;
    }

    .grid tbody tr th {
        border-style: none none none solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #CDE38A;
        height: 18px;
        padding: 4px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #658A07;
        padding-left: 12px !important;
    }


table.grid th[scope=col] {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px;
}


.grid a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: White;
}

.grid td {
    font-size: 8pt;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px !important;
    border: 1px solid #CDE38A;
    color: #717171;
}


.grid tbody tr {
    height: 18px;
}


    .grid tbody tr.alt {
        background: #EFF5E1;
    }


.pager {
    margin: 8px 0px 8px 4px;
}

    .pager a, .pager span {
        padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
        border: 1px solid #557504;
        background-color: #658A07;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

        .pager a:hover, .pager span {
            cursor: pointer;
            border-color: #57960B;
            background-color: #66AD10;
            color: #FFFFFF !important;
        }

.ajax-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #A7D0D9;
    opacity: .5;
}

.ajax-loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px; /* -1 * image width / 2 */
    margin-top: -32px; /* -1 * image height / 2 */
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.9;
}


.form {
    border: 1px solid #E0DBF2;
    background-color: #DDEBB2;
    padding: 12px;
    width: 670px;
}


.form-error {
    color: #CC3300;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.form input, .form select, .form textarea {
    outline: none;
    color: #5A5A87;
    padding: 2px;
}

.form input {
    padding: 3px;
}

.form table tr td {
    padding: 2px !important;
}

.form textarea, .form input[type="text"], .form input[type="number"], .form input[type="date"], .form select {
    border: 1px solid #E1DBEE;
    width: 414px;
}

.form select {
    width: 422px;
}


.form input[type="submit"], .form input[type="reset"], .form input[type="button"] {
    width: 100px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.form input[type="date"] {
    width: 140px;
}

.form input[type="radio"], .form input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin: 4px;
}

.label-cell {
    width: 210px !important;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 328px !important;
}

.sign-in-logo {
    width: 375px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 170px;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

.sign-in {
    width: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 280px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 12px;
}

    .sign-in input[type='text'], .sign-in input[type='password'] {
        width: 150px;
    }

    .sign-in select {
        width: 158px;
    }

    .sign-in:hover {
        background-color: #F0F0E0;
    }

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

#GridPanel {
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width:760px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

what am I doing wrong??

Comment: That's a lot of CSS you have there.... Is anyone going to bother to read that? And people have to guess what is what because you have given no `HTML`.

Comment: @Ruddy sorry this is my first question to stackoverflow..i will be careful next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table is wrapped in the following DIV: `<div id="GridPanel" style="width: 1563px; overflow: auto;">`

You have an inline fixed css width of 1563px and on line 506 in Main.css you have `max-width: 760px;` and `min-width: 400px;`. 
Since your width is higher then your max-width then your max-width will be used and your min-width will never be used.

If you set your width with the percent unit instead of pixel then it will resize with the screen and stop at your `min-width`.

Exemple: `<div id="GridPanel" style="width: 95%; overflow: auto;">`